# cmake find_package(GDAL REQURIED) can't locate lib and config

Tags: cmake, gdal

I am trying to add GDAL dependency in cmake. I installed GDAL with this [reference](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/gdal/#linux). Basically, there are two steps:

1. download GDAL from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks
2. echo 'export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
   source ~/.bash_profile

I checked with `gdalinfo --version` in terminal and get `GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24`. It seems that everything is fine.

However, when I use `FIND_PACKAGE(GDAL REQUIRED)` in my `CMakeLists.txt`. I am able to find the `GDAl_INCLUDE_DIR`, but not the other two (`GDAL_CONFIG` and `GDAL_LIBRARY`).

What am I missing here? Please help!

[image]

Comment: If the issue hasn't been resolved yet, which OS (and distro, if relevant) are you using?
Also: have you tried to manually specify path to the library file and to the config header file, and if so, what was the outcome?

Comment: I have solved this issue. I am using Mac OS Yosemite. But I didn't use the `GDAL 1.11.1` above. I compile the `GDAL 2.0dev` version from [source (github)](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal) and everything seems fine. I have not tried "manually specify path to the library file". Thanks.

Comment: I guess maybe there is some problem with the installer from [kyngchaos's site](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks)? Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Click on GDAL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND and enter the location where you install the libgdal. If you use homebrew, it will be /usr/local/lib